# two process using fifos and pipes don't want to communicate

Tags: c, fork

i'm currently learning linux and all that stuff about fork,fifos,pipes.
Basically, what i'm trying to do is to make communicate 2 process, those process communicate with 2 fifos -> P1 sends to P2 the pid of his child and this what P2 does aswell. once he got it, he sends it to his child which print it (via a pipe). (+ the child send back a number via a 2nd pipe)

It compiles with no errors, it runs, but nothing appears in the terminal.
Well, it's kinda hard to explain without drawing it, here is the code of the first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include "erreur.c"
#include <fcntl.h> //Pour O_WDONLY etc

int pidProc1;
int pidProc2;
int pfd01[2];
int pfd10[2];

main()
{
if((pipe(pfd01)) == -1) erreur("pipe");
if((pipe(pfd10)) == -1) erreur("pipe");
switch(pidProc1 = fork())
{
case 0 : fils();
case -1 : erreur("fork");
}
pere();
}

pere()
{
int fd12;
int fd21;   
char * chaine;
int nb;
    // On fait les ouvertures des fifos
if ((fd12 = open ("fifo12", O_RDONLY) ) == -1 ) erreur ("Ouverture fifo12 en lecture");
if ((fd21 = open ("fifo21", O_WRONLY) ) == -1 ) erreur ("Ouverture fifo21 en ecriture");

if (read (fd12, &pidProc2, sizeof(int) ) == -1)erreur("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    printf("Je suis P1 %d et je recupere le pid du fils de P2 : %d \n",getpid(),pidProc2);

if ( write(fd21, &pidProc1, sizeof(int)) ==-1 ) erreur("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
    printf("Envoi du pid de fils de P1 à P2 \n");

if(close(pfd01[0])==-1) erreur("close");

if ( write(pfd01[1], &pidProc2, sizeof(int)) ==-1 ) erreur("ccccccc");
    printf("Envoi du pid du fils de P2 à F1  \n");

if(close(pfd10[1])==-1) erreur("close");
if ( read(pfd10[0], &nb, sizeof(int)) ==-1 )    erreur("ddddddddddddd");
    printf("un numero!!! %d \n",nb);

}

fils()
{
if(close(pfd01[1])==-1) erreur("close");
if ( read(pfd01[0], &pidProc2, sizeof(int)) ==-1 )  erreur("dddddddddd");
    printf("Je suis le fils %d et j ai recu le pid du fils : %d",getpid(),pidProc2);

if(close(pfd10[0])==-1) erreur("close");
if ( write(pfd10[1], 7, sizeof(int)) ==-1 ) erreur("eee");
    printf("time for the son F1 to send something \n");

}
```

Here is the second one :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include "erreur.c"
#include <fcntl.h> //Pour O_WDONLY etc

int pidProc1;
int pidProc2;
int pfd02[2];
int pfd20[2];
main()
{
if((pipe(pfd02)) == -1) erreur("pipe");
if((pipe(pfd20)) == -1) erreur("pipe");
switch(pidProc2 = fork())
{
case 0 : fils();
case -1 : erreur("fork");
}
pere();
}

pere()
{
int fd12;
int fd21;   
int nb;
    // On fait les ouvertures des fifos
if ((fd21 = open ("fifo21", O_RDONLY) ) == -1 ) erreur ("Ouverture fifo21 en lecture");
if ((fd12 = open ("fifo12", O_WRONLY) ) == -1 ) erreur ("Ouverture fifo12 en ecriture");

if ( read(fd21, &pidProc1, sizeof(int)) ==-1 )  erreur("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
    printf("Je suis P2 %d et je recup l'id de l'autre fils tmtc : %d \n",getpid(),pidProc1);    

if (write (fd12, &pidProc2, sizeof(int) ) == -1)erreur("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    printf("Je suis P2 %d et je j'envoie le pid fils : %d \n",getpid(),pidProc2);


if(close(pfd02[0])==-1) erreur("close");
if ( write(pfd02[1], &pidProc1, sizeof(int)) ==-1 ) erreur("cccccc");
    printf("Envoi du pid du fils de P1 à F2 \n");


if(close(pfd20[1])==-1) erreur("close");
if ( read(pfd20[0], &nb, sizeof(int)) ==-1 )    erreur("dddddddddddd");
    printf("un numero!!! %d \n",nb);

}

fils()
{    
if(close(pfd02[1])==-1) erreur("close");
if ( read(pfd02[0], &pidProc1, sizeof(int)) ==-1 )  erreur("ddddddd");
    printf("Je suis le fils %d et j ai recu le pid fils : %d",getpid(),pidProc1);

if(close(pfd20[0])==-1) erreur("close");
if ( write(pfd20[1], 7, sizeof(int)) ==-1 ) erreur("eee");
    printf("time for the son F1 to send something \n");

}
```

Sorry for this long post! i'm learning so every tips is appreciated!

edit : For those who might test :
Here is my erreur.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h> //Pour O_WDONLY etc...

void erreur (char *message)
{   char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    strcpy (buffer, strerror(errno));
    fprintf (stderr, "Erreur: %s\terrno=%d (%s)\n", message, errno, buffer);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Well, your comment is appreciated but can you tell which mistakes you are talking about? I m developping in c for many years now.., i m just uncomfortable with Unix. The only "mistake" i m aware of is about my random number 7 in the write method, it s suposed to be a pointer i know, but i just wanted to catch an int. I d be glad if someone could explain what is wrong this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reference you first code as a, second as b

There are 2 deadlocks in your code:

1. when opening fifo, open and write should match, otherwise it'll block forever unless `O_NONBLOCK` is add to open mode. You may want to take a look at the man page of fifo with `man fifo`

   The FIFO must be opened  on
          both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed.
   Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

   so if code in a is:

   ```
   if ((fd12 = open ("fifo12", O_RDONLY) ) == -1 ) erreur ("Ouverture fifo12 en lecture");
   if ((fd21 = open ("fifo21", O_WRONLY) ) == -1 ) erreur ("Ouverture fifo21 en ecriture");
   ```

   in b code should be (notice it's reversed in your code)

   ```
   if ((fd12 = open ("fifo12", O_WRONLY) ) == -1 ) erreur ("Ouverture fifo12 en ecriture");
   if ((fd21 = open ("fifo21", O_RDONLY) ) == -1 ) erreur ("Ouverture fifo21 en lecture");
   ```
2. read and write should match, in your code a and b try to read from fifo while no one write to it, so deadlock.

   if code in a is:

   ```
   if (read (fd12, &pidProc2, sizeof(int) ) == -1)erreur("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
       printf("Je suis P1 %d et je recupere le pid du fils de P2 : %d \n",getpid(),pidProc2);
   if ( write(fd21, &pidProc1, sizeof(int)) ==-1 ) erreur("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
       printf("Envoi du pid de fils de P1 à P2 \n");
   ```

   in b code should be: (it's reversed in your code)

   ```
   if (write (fd12, &pidProc2, sizeof(int) ) == -1)erreur("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
       printf("Je suis P2 %d et je j'envoie le pid fils : %d \n",getpid(),pidProc2);
   if ( read(fd21, &pidProc1, sizeof(int)) ==-1 )  erreur("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
       printf("Je suis P2 %d et je recup l'id de l'autre fils tmtc : %d \n",getpid(),pidProc1);
   ```